# YQL not returning data from balance sheet or income statement

Tags: yql, finance, yahoo-finance

I have been trying to use YQL to access the fundamentals of listed companies. But what is showing up in the Yahoo finance page is not being returned from YQL queries. Specifically I need to retrieve data from balance sheet and income statement, a sample query for [Apple](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL) in YQL is like:

`SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.balancesheet WHERE symbol='AAPL'`

This, however, only returns a time frame (quarterly), and nothing else.

Link to YQL console of my sample query is [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=SELECT+*+FROM+yahoo.finance.balancesheet+WHERE+symbol%3D'AAPL')

Is the data inaccessible to YQL or is there anything wrong with the way I am running the query? How can I get a complete list of data as in http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL through YQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query used to work fine. However, a month or two ago, a number of yahoo.finance YQL "tables" stopped working.

IOW, you are doing it right, but YQL is broken.

If you mouse over the `yahoo.finance.balancesheet` entry in the left column of the YQL console, buttons labeled **desc** and **src** appear. If you click **src**, it fetches the scraping code for you: http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.balancesheet.xml. To make the [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X) JavaScript legible, right-click and select View Source or use `wget` or `curl` from the command line.

Notice that the code fetches http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL&quarterly and then uses an XPath query to find the data:

```
var query = y.xpath(rawresult, "//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr/td/table/tr");
```

If you fetch the [page](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=AAPL&quarterly) into your browser and inspect the HTML, you find that there is indeed a `table` with class `yfnc_tabledata1`. However, it has no `tr` direct child. Apparently, Yahoo must have decided to add a `tbody` element. That probably explains why the query no longer scrapes any data.

The code page lists Ryan Hoium as the author. A little googling leads to the [github repository](https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/tree/master/yahoo/finance) where the code lives, alongside the code for the other Yahoo Finance tables.

Sadly, only the `yahoo.finance.sectors` table has received recent attention. The change was to add double slashes to its XPath expression. Double-slashes relax the "direct child" requirement, allowing, for example, `tr` to still be found even if there is an intervening `tbody`. However, it appears the new version has not been pushed out to the public site.

Comment: Indeed, I think it's the problem they are facing right now. But don't know when it's gonna be fixed. From their repo (https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/tree/master/yahoo/finance) it looks like no one has been actively updating it